# How to use for each loop with odd index in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, for-loop, foreach

I'm trying using excel4node to convert my data into excel,

here is my code:

```
names = ['AA','BB','CC']

names.forEach((title, index) => {
    sheet.cell(1, index, 1, index + 1, true).string(title);

    index += 2;
});
```

the problem is i want to only use odd number as index in this loop.

expecting sheet.cell code in loop like this:

```
sheet.cell(1, "1", 1, "2", true).string(title[0])
sheet.cell(1, "3", 1, "4", true).string(title[1])
sheet.cell(1, "5", 1, "6", true).string(title[2])
```

so how do i skip the even index number in for each loop

I tried used index += 2 or in the beginning of the loop (title, index = 1) or use continue, but won't work...

please help, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can do like this.

`sheet.cell(1, 2 * index + 1, 1, 2 * index + 2, true).string(title);`

Comment: this works!!! i spend almost 4 hour stack in here :( sir you just save my day

Answer (score 0):

`index += 2` does nothing. `index` is a local variable in a callback, its scope ends at the end of the callback body.
Also `continue` does nothing since it's not a `for` loop.
You can try:

```
names.forEach((title, index) => {
  if (index % 2 === 0) return;
  sheet.cell(1, index, 1, index + 1, true).string(title);
});
```

Comment: i've tried this method, but it won't work too, i think it's excel4node's problem :(

Comment: You will lose even titles with above code, because ``if(index%2===0) return``

Comment: @BTSM I thought it was what OP wanted. I probably misunderstood the question

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to say that there is no problem with excel4node.

Comment: @BTSM you are right, there is no problem with excel4node, my question is not precise.